# Weird behaviour of generator unpacking in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, iterator, generator, iterable-unpacking

I am currently trying to be more familiar with iterators in Python, and I encountered some weird behaviour. Essentially, I get the wrong behaviour with a generator comprehension, but the correct behaviour with a list comprehension.

**Let me start by explaining what I try to do, and then what behaviour I get.**
Imagine having a dictionary of iterables, e.g.

```
d = {'a': [1, 2, 3], 'b': [4, 5]}
```

What I want is to have a list of dictionaries with all possible combinations of the iterable. For the first example, this would be

```
l = [
        {'a': 1, 'b': 4},
        {'a': 1, 'b': 5},
        {'a': 2, 'b': 4},
        {'a': 2, 'b': 5},
        {'a': 3, 'b': 4},
        {'a': 3, 'b': 5},
    ]
```

To do this, I created this generator:

```
def dict_value_iterator(d):
    for k, v in d.items():         
        yield ((k, vi) for vi in v)
```

The idea was to run the following code to get the wanted result

```
def get_all_dicts(d):
    return map(dict, *itertools.product(dict_value_iterator(d)))
```

**Now, for the strange behaviour.**
To test that the `dict_value_iterator` generator indeed did what I hoped it would, I ran the following code:

```
for i in dict_value_iterator(d):
    print(list(i))
```

which indeed does what I hoped it would, namely print out the following:

```
[('a', 1), ('a', 2), ('a', 3)]
[('b', 4), ('b', 5)]
```

However, when I run the following code

```
def test_unpacking(*args):
    for a in args:
        print(list(a))
test_unpacking(*dict_value_iterator(d))
```

I get the output

```
[('b', 1), ('b', 2), ('b', 3)]
[('b', 4), ('b', 5)]
```

This makes little to no sense for me, why does iterator unpacking change anything.

**Final note.**
The way I found it was by running the  `get_all_dicts` function on d, which resulted in the following output

```
[{'b': 4}, {'b': 5}, {'b': 4}, {'b': 5}, {'b': 4}, {'b': 5}]
```

However, when I modify the `dict_value_iterator` as follows

```
def dict_value_iterator(d):
    for k, v in d.items():         
        yield ((k, vi) for vi in v)
```

I get this output

```
[{'a': 1, 'b': 4},
 {'a': 1, 'b': 5},
 {'a': 2, 'b': 4},
 {'a': 2, 'b': 5},
 {'a': 3, 'b': 4},
 {'a': 3, 'b': 5}]
```

which is what I want.

Comment: Interesting question, wonder if this is complicated by the fact that you have created a generator returning a generator

Comment: Generators execute in a lazy fashion - that is, until you actually call `print(list(a))` in your `test_unpacking()` function the whole `((k, vi) for vi in v)` generator from the `dict_value_iterator()` function doesn't have a value. Since you're unpacking the arguments when calling `test_unpacking()`, you force your `dict_value_iterator()` to execute its whole loop (to exhaust the generator) which means that `k`, which will be used moments later within your generator will have the latest value in the loop - `b` in your case - for all of the _generated_ generators.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here’s a simplified version:

```
generators = []

for i in [1, 2]:
    generators.append((i for _ in [1]))

print(list(generators[0]))  # [2]
```

Only a single variable called `i` exists, and the `for` loop sets it repeatedly. All generators created by the generator expression refer to the same `i` and don’t read it until the loop has exited.

One way to fix it is by creating another scope with a function (like you would in ES5, for example):

```
def dict_value_iterator(d):
    def get_generator(k, v):
        return ((k, vi) for vi in v)

    for k, v in d.items():         
        yield get_generator(k, v)
```